# Probability density for continuous RVs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I had to solve the following question in the final examination of my probability course and I wish to know what exactly is wrong with my solution:

Q. Let a point be chosen uniformly from the interior of a
triangle having a base of length l and height h from the base. Let X
be defined as the distance of the point chosen to the base. Find the
distribution function of X.

My answer:

Consider line $l_{1}$ such that it is at a distance "x" from the base of the triangle, and let $h_{1}$ be the corresponding distance from the tip of the triangle to $l_{1}$. Then, the probability density is given by:

length($l_{1}$)/Area of the triangle
= ($l*h_{1}/h$)/(hl/2)
= $2h_{1}$/$h^2$
= $2(h - x)/h^2$

Upon integrating this (w.r.t x), we will find the probability distribution function to be: $2x(h - x)/h^2$

The results that I got are all correct (they match the given solution). The total probability of the density comes out to be 1. However, my professor says that I cannot find the density in this manner because I have to take the area of the line and divide it by the area of the triangle, which will be zero. My thought here is that I am not finding the distribution, only the density first, hence I went by the traditional definition of what a probability is (occurrences of an element/total sample space) and got the above. Is this not a valid method?

Comment: Why does the length of the line segment  matter?  The probability that your point will be on a line segment (of any length) is $0$.  Better to take a thin trapezoid around your line, or something like that.